# Can we change default browser/engine form chromium to any other for webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl> 12-29 11:13:09.030  21472-21472/hiteshpc.nxsameple I/art﹕ 
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl> 12-29 11:13:09.089  21472-21472/hiteshpc.nxsameple I/art﹕     
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback> 12-29 11:13:09.089 21472-21472/hiteshpc.nxsameple I/art﹕
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
```

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Mikel I changed the approach. are you trying to use `setWebChromeClient` ?

Comment: Can you post what you did differently as the solution for this?

Comment: Hi i am facing similar problem . What solution did you apply for it

Comment: @beginner Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @FauxPas Did you find a solution ?